# IPFS only connect with specified Nodes

Tags: blockchain, ipfs

we know we can connect and disconnect with specified nodes in IPFS i.e

```
ipfs swarm connect /ip4/104.236.176.52/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLnSGccFuZQJzRadHn95W2CrSFmZuTdDWP8HXaHca9z
```

But what i want to look into is that i only specified or some sort of authorized nodes. Because i want to share my data with only some specified nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You don't need to connect to the public ipfs network.

Instead you can create your own private ipfs network with nodes that share a common shared symmetric key.

[Here](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/experimental-features.md#private-networks) are the specific details on how to setup a private ipfs network.